# Find at least one word of interest in a vector of sentences using R

Tags: r, string, loops, vector

I have a vector of strings ("sentences"), where each sentence has different number of different words in them:

```
sentences <- c("word01 word02",
               "word01 word04 word03",
               "word10",
               "",
               "word02 word07 word08 word09",
               ...)
```

I also have a vector of words of interest:

```
wordsOfInterest <- c("word01", "word02", ...)
```

I want to know if at least one of the wordsOfInterest is found in each of the sentences. The output should be a logical vector with length identical to that of the sentences vector. Thus, given the vectors above, the output vector should have values

```
TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
```

The number of sentences depends on the dataset and can be anything from few to around one hundred thousand, the number of words in each sentence can be anything from zero to around one hundred, and the number of wordsOfInterest can be anything from one to around one hundred.

Furthermore, I have several datasets to analyze, each with several individual sentence vectors.  Then there are several sets of wordsOfInterest vectors that I need to apply to each sentence vector in each dataset, so the cumulative computational requirements start to add up.

Only succesful solution I've come up so far is to use str_detect one by one for each wordsOfInterest and applying it to the various sentences vector, but of course I'd like to find another solution.  I've tried to get my head around this using the native vectorization as well as FOR loops in R but to no avail. So I have two problems, how to do it to begin with, and then how to do it as fast (both computation and typing-wise) as possible. I appreciate all help.

Comment: You can use `grepl` `grepl(paste(wordsOfInterest, collapse="|"), sentences)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grepl()` and collapse your `wordsOfInterest` to include `|` and `\\b` edge of word checks around each word. This prevents partial matches, such as finding "then" when the word of interest is "the".

```
matchString <- paste0(wordsOfInterest, collapse = "\\b|")
matchString <- paste0("\\b", matchString, "\\b")
grepl(pattern = matchString, x = sentences)
```

Confirmed using the following:

```
wordsOfInterest <- sample(1:1000000, 100)
sentences <- ""
for(i in 1:sample(1:100, 1)){
  sentences <- c(sentences,paste(sample(1:1000000, sample(0:100)), collapse = " "))
}

matchString <- paste(wordsOfInterest, collapse = "\\s+|")
grepl(pattern = matchString, x = sentences)
```

Regarding the throughput of the `grepl()` call: For 64,000 sentences of the lengths you specified, it took ~1.36 seconds.

```
> length(sentences)
[1] 63470
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(grepl(pattern = matchString, x = sentences), times = 10)
Unit: seconds
min       lq     mean   median       uq      max      neval
1.280757 1.317157 1.357845 1.337714 1.374004 1.554918    10
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `\\b` for word boundaries instead of `\\s+` for whitespace... it's more general in case the input has punctuation, and in case the same pattern ends up getting used for extraction it won't extract the whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new @Gregor. Updated based on your advice.